# Consultar 3 tablas relacionadas con Eloquent ORM Laravel 7x

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

Deseo relacionar 3 tablas con **Eloquent** y mostrarlo en formato **JSON**. Los modelos se llaman **Departamento**, **Categoria**, **Producto**. Las relaciones de las tablas son de ***uno a muchos***.

**Modelo Departamento**

```
class Departamento extends Model
{
    public function categorias()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Categoria::class, 'IdD', 'IdD');
    }

    public function productos()
    {    
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Producto::class, Categoria::class, 'IdD', 'IdC', 'IdD', 'IdC');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Categoria**

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    public function productos()
        {
          return $this->hasMany(Categoria::class, 'IdC', 'IdC');
        }
}
```

**Modelo Producto**

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    public function categoria()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'IdC', 'IdC');
    }
}
```

**API**

```
Route::get('productos', function ()
{
    $data = Departamento::with('categorias', 'productos')->get();
    return response()->json(['categoriass' => $data]);
});
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no logro colocar a ***productos*** dentro de ***categorias*** en **JSON**, no se como formularlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), existen dos tipos de carga de relaciones:

Relaciones Multiples (en el mismo nivel)

```
 $books = App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();
```

Relaciones anidadas (en un nivel interior)

```
 $books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

Por tanto, para el caso que indicas la llamada deberia ser:

```
Route::get('productos', function ()
{
  $data = Departamento::with('categorias.productos')->get();
  return response()->json(['categoriass' => $data]);
});
```